# Leaflet: Architecture for draggable markers within connected lines

Tags: javascript, leaflet, draggable

I am developing a schematic/diagram editor based on leaflet. Essentially this is any number of interactive (i.e draggable) markers connected by polylines:

[image]

I would like to develop the system so that when the markers are dragged, the connected polylines are redrawn to be dragged along with them.

Currently, the marker and polyline are unaware of each other. 
The marker is a custom class extending L.marker and the polyline is likewise extending L.Polyline.
L.Map has been extended to provide 'addComponent' (Component == marker) and 'linkComponents' methods.

My first thought arhictecture-wise was to hold a reference to each connected polyline on the marker itself. Then I can override the drag handler to redraw each polyline.

This posed 2 problems:

- How does the marker know which 'end' of the polyline do I need to change the coordinates of?
- At some point I want to be able to delete the lines individually by some user interaction. If I do this, the connected
  marker will now be holding a reference to a polyline which doesnt
  exist! So a way around this would be to have each polyline *also*
  hold a reference to the markers they connect to. But now it seems to
  be getting a little fragile, with multiple places in which I might
  need to update information.

So I am looking for suggestions on sensible methods/patterns to implement this functionality

Comment: I think you'll need to maintain a collection of all pairs of markers that are connected; to draw lines between them on a Leaflet map, please follow this Q&A: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53394/select-two-markers-draw-line-between-them-in-leaflet

Comment: Take inspiration from Leaflet.draw plugin. There are also numerous other geometry edition plugins listed on Leaflet plugins page.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, or at least *an* answer was for me to stop thinking like an enterprisey OO-obsessed developer and utilize leaflets event system.

When I create the polyline, I pass in the originating marker(s) in order to calculate the start and end points of the polyline:

```
const Link = L.Polyline.extend({

  options: {
    fromIcon: null,
    fromPort: null,
    toIcon: null,
    toPort: null
  },

  initialize: function(latlngs, options) {
    L.Util.setOptions(this, options);

    // We will insert the 'from port' coordinate at the start and the
    // 'to' coordinate at the end. 
    // 'getPortLocation' is just a simple function to return the LatLng of where a line should start to be drawn over a 'port'
    const start = this.options.fromIcon.getPortLocation(this.options.fromPort);
    const end = this.options.toIcon.getPortLocation(this.options.toPort);

    // Insert port positions at the start and end af the latlng array.
    latlngs.unshift(start);
    latlngs.push(end);
    this._setLatLngs(latlngs);
  }
}
```

An easy solution was to simply listen to the drag events:

```
    // Make sure the line is updated when the connected markers are moved
    this.options.fromIcon.on('drag', (event) => this.fromDragHandler(event, this.options.fromPort));
    this.options.toIcon.on('drag', (event) => this.toDragHandler(event, this.options.toPort));
```

And redraw the line:

```
fromDragHandler: function(event, portNum) {
  const marker = event.target;
  const latlngs = this.getLatLngs();
  const newPos = marker.getPortLocation(portNum);
  latlngs[0] = newPos;
  this.setLatLngs(latlngs);
}
```

Had I thought a little harder and browsed some more code before asking....

Comment: this is a brilliant approach !